# I have a problem with the Course of Kotlin from Android. @Composable Text() doesn't take String

Tags: android, kotlin, text, android-compose-textfield

I'd like to know why Text() in Jetpack Compose (Kotlin) can't take String as an argument in this case? I am following the course from Android and I exactly did what they did (the course is from 6 march  2023). If you have any clue, let me know. Thanks

(Don't pay attention to the nature of my code)

First image of my code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKbKE.png)
partial image of the error(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Kjf.png)

Argument should've been taken.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is:

```
Text(
  text = message,
  fontsSize = 36.sp
)
```

But there is no parameter called `fontsSize` - that's why you're getting an error. You have to use the right name - `fontSize`:

```
Text(
  text = message,
  fontSize = 36.sp
)
```